# Show that if $S,T$ are linear transformations $N(ST) \leq N(S) + N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces

I have a finite dimensional vectors space $V$, and two linear transformations on $V$, $S$ and $T$.

I need to show that $N(ST) \leq N(S) + N(T)$. Can anybody spot what is wrong with this argument:

$N(ST) = \dim(\ker(ST))$ now call $S1$ the restriction of $S$ to $\text{Im }T$, so $\ker(S1) = \ker(S)$ intersect $\text{Im }(T)$ so then $N(S1) < N(S)$ hence $N(ST) < N(S)$?

Comment: If $T$ is the zero map you certainly won't have nullity of $ST$ less than nullity of $S$.

Comment: What is the relation of $N(S1)$ and $N(ST)$? For sure it's not $N(ST)\leq N(S1)$.

Comment: @HSN, could be; anyway, it's back to $N(ST)$ now. Maybe the question has converged to a limit.... My very first comment still applies, though.

Comment: Is it not true that ker(S1) = ker(ST) = ker(S1) intersect im(T)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=\dim V$ and $S_1$ the restriction of $S$ to $\mathrm{Im} T$ so 
$$\mathrm{Im}(S_1)=\mathrm{Im}(ST)\quad\text{and}\quad \ker S_1=\ker S\cap \mathrm{Im} T$$
The rank nullity theorem gives
$$\mathrm{rank}(ST)=\mathrm{rank}(T)-\dim(\ker S\cap \mathrm{Im} T)\geq \mathrm{rank} T- N(S)\geq \mathrm{rank} T-(n-\mathrm{rank} S)$$
hence we find
$$n-\mathrm{rank} S-\mathrm{rank} T\geq -\mathrm{rank}(ST)$$
and by the rank nullity theorem we have
$$N(ST)\leq N(S)+N(T)$$

Comment: If $T$ is zero and $S$ is non zero...

Comment: @Vishal Do you find a problem when $T=0$?

Comment: If $T$ is zero, so is $ST$, and then no way can the nullity of $ST$ be less than equal to nullity of $S$ if $S$ is non-zero. I did not scan the proof, but it must have some mistake.

Comment: @Vishal I never said that nullity of $ST$ is less than equal to  nullity of $S$, where you see it? The result which I proved is $N(ST)\leq N(S)+N(T)$ which is true even if $T=0$.