# Nullity of composition of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^k$ and $U : \mathbb{R}^k → \mathbb{R}^m$ be linear maps. How can I show that

**nullity(U ◦ T) ≤ nullity(U) + nullity(T)?**

I am certain that I will have to use the rank-nullity theorem but I do not know how to use it and prove the above statement.

Any solution without using restrictions?

Comment: See if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409294/show-that-if-s-t-are-linear-transformations-nst-leq-ns-nt) answers your question.

Comment: It does but is there no more elementary way to go about this? Something without restriction as I have not been taught that.

Answer (score 1):

The proof below, if correct, is based in a slightly general case. I solved this exercise some time ago (not very much time ago) and I had in my notes (this is the exercise 3.B.22 of *Linear algebra done right* third edition).

About notation: FTLA is the named *fundamental theorem of linear algebra* that state that

$$\dim V=\dim T(U)+\dim(\ker T)$$

for $T\in\mathcal L(U,V)$.

---

Let $U,V$ finite-dimensional vector spaces and $S\in\mathcal L(V,W)$, $T\in\mathcal L (U,V)$, and we must show that

$$\dim\ker(ST)\le\dim\ker(T)+\dim\ker(S)\tag{1}$$

Now because $U':=\ker(ST)$ is a subspace of $U$ with $T':=T|_{U'}$ applying the FTLA we have that

$$\dim U'=\dim\ker(T')+\dim T'(U')\tag{2}$$

and because $\ker(T')=\ker(T)$ then $(2)$ becomes

$$\dim\ker(ST)=\dim\ker(T)+\dim T'(U')\tag{3}$$

Now if $T$ is surjective $\dim T'(U')=\dim\ker(S)$ so $(3)$ becomes the equality in $(1)$.

If $T$ is not surjective is possible that $\dim T'(U')<\dim\ker(S)$, when exists some $Sv=0$ such that $v\notin T(U)$. In any case we have that

$$T'(U')=T(U')\subseteq \ker(S)$$

because if $STu=0$ then $Tu\in\ker(S)$. Hence

$$\dim T'(U')\le\dim\ker(S)$$

and $(1)$ holds.

---

Ah, I had seen that the rank nullity theorem is equivalent to the FTLA. Sorry, I dont know a way to solve this exercise without some version of this theorem.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but your solution is a bit beyond what I have been taught yet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @angrez dont be confused by the different notation, the FTLA is equivalent to the rank-nullity theorem. $S$ and $T$ are linear maps and $ST:=S\circ T$ it composition. The nullity of $T$ is the same that the dimension of it kernel (also called null space). $\dim$ means "dimension of", $\ker$ means "kernel or null space of", and $T(U)$ is just the image of $T$ (because it domain is $U$).

Comment: But what is U′? All the things you just said I got it but I thought that U′ is some special map that I do not know about and hence thought the solution was a bit beyond. Thanks for the clarification btw.

Comment: I defined $U'$ is my answer, the symbol $:=$ means "defined as", that is, $U'$ is the null space (the kernel) of $ST$

Comment: got it. Thank you so much!